# Взаимодействие input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет.

У меня есть 4 `input'a`. Как мне сделать, что бы когда я вводил цифру в первый, то во-втором выводилась цифра из формулы `2x+1`. В третьем выводилось число из формулы `x^2` относительно второго `input'a`, а в четвёртом относительно третьего по формуле `3x/x^2`?

Я попробовал написать свой код, но он почему то не начал работать с первой секунды

```js
$(function() {
  $('#number_0').onkeypress(function() {
    $('#number_1').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <span>Ваше число: </span><input type="number" id="number_0">
</p>
<p>
  <span>A1: </span><input type="number" id="number_1" readonly>
</p>
<p>
  <span>A2: </span><input type="number" id="number_2" readonly>
</p>
<p>
  <span>A3: </span><input type="number" id="number_3" readonly>
</p>
```

Comment: Обычно используют не onkeypress, а onchange: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша первая проблема, с которой вы столкнулись, это то, что в JQuery функции назначаются без `on`

*Пример:*

```
$(element).click(function() {...});
```

*Или же вот так:*

```
$(element).on('click', function() {..});
```

**Решение:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#number_0').keyup(function() {
    // Приводим значение в цифренный формат и решаем уравнение
    var num = 2 * parseFloat($(this).val()) + 1;
    // Присваиваем значение
    $('#number_1').val(num).change();
  });
  
  $('#number_1').on('change', function() {
    // Приводим значение в цифренный формат и решаем уравнение
    var num = parseFloat($(this).val()) ^ 2;
    // Присваиваем значение
    $('#number_2').val(num).change();
  });
  
  $('#number_2').on('change', function() {
    // Приводим значение в цифренный формат и решаем уравнение
    var num = ( parseFloat($(this).val()) * 3 ) / ( parseFloat($(this).val()) ^ 2 );
    // Присваиваем значение
    $('#number_3').val(num).change();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <span>Ваше число: </span><input type="number" id="number_0">
</p>
<p>
  <span>A1: </span><input type="number" id="number_1" readonly>
</p>
<p>
  <span>A2: </span><input type="number" id="number_2" readonly>
</p>
<p>
  <span>A3: </span><input type="number" id="number_3" readonly>
</p>
```

Ещё для вывода не подойдёт `keypress` т.к. он выдаст предыдущее значение. Если уж использовать `key`, то уже `keyup`

Comment: Спасибо!!!! Это то что нужно